# Is raising a hot Zener diode from the PCB (for better ventilation) a bad idea?

Tags: temperature, zener, thermal, heatsink

Whenever I rework a Zener diode which has been running too hot (i.e. failed), I like to replace it with a higher-power equivalent when possible, and (if through-hole) raise it slightly off the board for better ventilation.  That seems to work well; no complaints so far.

Then I ran into this, from the [1N53 series datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/1n5333b-d.pdf):

[image: 1N53 series lead-length derating...]

It seems long leads can drastically increase °C/W, a lot more than I thought it would, even for short lengths.  Should I instead have been *reducing* the lead length as much as possible?

Are there any other suggestions for handling such problematic Zener diodes?

Comment: No surprise there: the wire has a thermal resistance, pretty much like it has an electrical one, so that increases linearly with length. The question is: how well does the board you solder it to act as heat sink? That's not as easy to model, as it depends on factors like board temperature, available copper for heat conduction and ventilation... But my gut feeling says: the first few millimeters might drastically increase ventilation, while raising it 3 or 4 cm should make practically difference in terms of fresh air. So, barring the ability to run a air flow thermal simulation: I think you're

Comment: doing well giving the thing 2 mm or maybe 4mm space to get convection going, but after that, the downsides taper off. But: I'm not experienced with this at all. this is gut feeling in its purest form. I could just as well demand you keep purity of essence by washing your diode in rain water and grain alcohol, and it would have the same kind of authority.

Comment: @MarcusMüller.  Or , How I learned to Stop Worrying and Love The Zener.  POE

Comment: Consider what that datasheet calls a "heatsink".   Soldering to a couple traces on a PCB is not a "heatsink".    Raising the diode a bit probably will help, but also consider that makes the part more susceptible to damage (i.e. from vibration in use or even from handling during product assembly)   A hot component can, over years, slowly char the PCB and oxidize the solder (turning it to a kind of compressed dust consistency), causing a failure.  Lifting it off the board prevents that possibility.  IMO, whether or not to lift it depends largely on the expected lifetime of the equipment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's an **exceptionally** small package to expect to get anything like 5W out of. To a first approximation, all the heat is going to be coming out of those fat 1mm\$\phi\$ leads. Here is another figure from a [different](https://datasheet.ciiva.com/360/p6ke6-8a-d-360999.pdf) device using the same package:

[image]

If the pads on your zener are connected directly to maybe 20mm x 20mm copper on each side you might get 40°/W so for an ambient of 60°C and maximum Tj of 150°C you'd be about to get a bit over 2W.

If your actual power dissipation is anything much over a fraction of 1W and there isn't a ton of copper on the PCB I'd be thinking about trying to retrofit something like this (photo from [EEVBLOG](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/stange-heat-sink/)):

[image]

Maybe just solder a "flag" of copper to each end of the lead if length permits.

Or, better, try to come up with a design that doesn't require so much power dissipation.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet values are showing you an unrealistic scenario; what the datasheet is showing is the thermal impedance when both leads are terminated in very good (perhaps perfect, if the values are calculated and not measured, which is likely) heatsinks rather than the copper foil on the PCB that they would actually be connected to.

Mounting the diode elevated off the board is not a bad idea--*if* you have forced airflow. Having the diode elevated means that the forced air will more effectively carry heat away from it, since the airflow can reach all sides of the diode and isn't impeded as much by other nearby parts on the board.

If you don't have forced airflow, however, it's possible that you would actually find the diode gets hotter, since the PCB traces can't conduct heat away as much--just like you suspected from that graph, longer leads have higher thermal impedance. The long leads will act to some extent as a heatsink and help to dissipate heat into the air, but it's quite possible they would do a worse job of it than the PCB traces, especially a ground plane, depending on how your board is laid out.

If you really need to dissipate a lot of power, I suggest you do what Spehro's answer suggests and mount the diode onto a heatsink. Better, though, to run your zener at lower current, and perhaps buffer the reference so generated with an op amp.