# Considerations for ratings when replacing a power resistor on a vintage PSU

Tags: resistors

I am replacing a component on a vintage PSU (1986). The component is an 8.2 kΩ wirewound power resistor.

The resistor might actually be newer than the board; it looks to have been installed after the factory, as it seems like a smaller resistor was previously in this position (judging by the additional hole that was drilled for this resistor).

I thought I had identified the correct resistor (5 W), but when it arrived I noticed that the original component was larger. Could it be the case that the original resistor is a higher power, or do newer power resistors tend to be smaller?

Old vs new resistor:
[image: Resistors]

In case you're wondering, I extended the legs on the old resistor to lift it off the board, as originally it was installed directly on the board which caused a burn mark. I imagine this wouldn't have affected functionality, but elevating it from the board's surface seemed prudent to me. That said, I appreciate the damage is already done in terms of the burn mark. The original resistor is fine (measures same resistance), but extending the legs like this didn't seem like a neat fix, hence why I want to replace it.

However, installing a physically smaller resistor makes me nervous, as I know it'll run hotter. That said, I am measuring 130 VAC across the resistor when the board is powered on, so it appears to only be passing 2.06098 W. When the PSU is turned on, the original resistor reached about 100 °C, and the new resistor measures <s>around the same</s> 140 °C. Though, the new resistor did burn-in when originally installed (a few whiffs of white smoke). According to the new resistor's datasheet ([VISH-S-A0011539484-1.pdf](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/VISH/VISH-S-A0011539484/VISH-S-A0011539484-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0)), the maximum operating temperature is 250 °C.

New resistor in place:
[image: PSU board]

Schematic for Commodore PC-1 PSU:
[image: Schematic]

Edit: This might not be exactly the right schematic; I’m actually struggling to identify exactly which resistor it is. The resistor is connected to the IC on pin 9, so looks like a voltage sense resistor or maybe the bootstrap power supply (which looks like R12). Pin 9 is also connected to the transformer via a diode, so certainly looks like IC VCC to me. On the board, the resistor is connected to the line filter via a diode, and I can't see this component arrangement on the schematic, so perhaps the board is a newer revision.

Edit: For GodJihyo...

[image: Bendy legs]

> Going forward, when replacing resistors and mounting them up off the board like that put a little U bend in the lead where it goes through the board. As it is, the only thing holding it in place is the circuit trace on the bottom of the board and eventually vibration will cause the trace to delaminate from the board. It's a bit like a crocodile's jaws, it's only got strength in one direction, it won't pull up so easy but it doesn't take much to push it down, tearing the traces off. A bend on the top side of the board will help prevent this.

Comment: could you please add the designator (R?) for the 8.2K resistor, so we can situate it on the schematic (which lacks the value of the components)

Comment: You need to know the power rating of the original resistor or replacing it will be tricky. The size is not necessarily a good indicator at all, these come in different shapes and materials.

Comment: It seems doubtful that the old resistor had the legs extended to keep it clear of the PCB, it looks like a recycled component that had previously had the legs cropped very short and couldn’t easily be fitted into this board.

Comment: Depending on which resistor that is (update the designator), it is possible that there is a problem elsewhere on the board and this resistor heats up. For instance, the regulator is supposed to generate it's own supply after it has started. If it can't generate it's own supply, it pulls too much current via the startup circuit.

Comment: Is this you? - https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/11gxc93/commodore_pc1_psu_no_power_on_any_rail_trying_to/?rdt=52760

Comment: Actually no, that’s not my post, but it is the same board. I’m fixing the board for a friend (who is the OP on that Reddit thread).

Comment: So, I’m actually struggling to identify which resistor it is. I suppose it’s possible that the schematic doesn’t exactly match the board. The resistor is connected to the IC, pretty sure on pin 9. It’s also connected to the line filter via a diode. I’m struggling to find this component arrangement on the schematic.

Comment: The old resistor has extended legs because I extended them; it was originally fitted very close to the board, hence the burn marks. Yes, the leads are very tightly cropped, but that’s how it was when I removed it from the board.

Comment: [Extending a component off the board for better cooling](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/576258) may actually make temperatures *worse*, careful.

Answer (score 2):

If the new resistor is smaller (with similar shape and outside materials), then it has either lower power ratings than the old, or will run hotter (maybe the old one was also a 5 W resistor, but with max temperature at for example 150°C instead of 250°C).

So, independently of the power ratings, if your new resistor is smaller but otherwise similar in shape, you can expect it to run hotter than the old one (it's just thermodynamics: you generate the same amount of heat (because the resistance has the same value), but you have less surface to dissipate it through).

So excepted if your old resistor was damaged (check if resistance is still 8.2 kΩ or significantly different), I would assume that your new resistor will run even hotter than the old one (excepted maybe for the fact you separate it from the PCB). So if the old one managed to make your PCB blacken, then I think it's not a good idea to use one becoming even hotter (the resistor might survive, but the PCB?).

If you get enough space, I would recommend you use a resistor with a surface at least as big as the old one, ideally bigger. A resistor with cooling fins or a heat plate might also be a good option. If you have enough height, you can make the resistor "stand" to manage to put a far longer one on the same position.

NB: if the resistor is partially shorted (i.e. resistance is far lower), then you are probably fine with just using the new one.

Comment: K = kelvin. k = kilo.

Comment: Wirewound heat sink resistors are pretty darn big though. Agreed that you don't have to worry about power rating then (they handle some 50W), but how to mount one and protect against accidental shorts against different components might be tricky. Ideally they should be placed prone against a metal surface.

Comment: @AndrewMorton : yes, by height, I mean space in the vertical direction

Comment: _"So if the old one managed to make your PCB blacken, then I think it's not a good idea to use one becoming even hotter"_ - On the other hand, both resistors will generate the same amount of heat, so if the resistor is far enough from other components, it shouldn't affect them more.

Comment: sure, it might be far enough not to damage the PCB because it is far enough.
Personally, I'd rather avoid any component getting hot enough to burn the PCB if I can avoid it, even if it is at "safe" distance.

Comment: I installed the new one standing with about 1 cm of clearance.

Comment: Correction: 0.5 cm

Comment: @NickBolton Going forward, when replacing resistors and mounting them up off the board like that put a little U bend in the lead where it goes through the board. As it is, the only thing holding it in place is the circuit trace on the bottom of the board and eventually vibration will cause the trace to delaminate from the board. It's a bit like a crocodile's jaws, it's only got strength in one direction, it won't pull up so easy but it doesn't take much to push it down, tearing the traces off. A bend on the top side of the board will help prevent this.

Comment: @GodJihyo Check out OP... How's that? Not going to win any beauty contests, but it does the job; I can apply quite a bit of force to the top side now without it applying force on the traces.

Comment: @Sandro Ah, so I measured the new resistor with an infrared heat sensor, and yeah it's running at about 140°C (max rating of 250°C).

Comment: @NickBolton Better. I used to work on some equipment where someone else had ‘upgraded’ a bunch of power resistors to higher power ones but left the leads straight. Between the heat of the resistors, soldering, and vibration many of the traces were ruined. A little kink in the lead makes a big difference.